# Is there a way to slow down firefox execution speed in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriverwait

I'm developing a new selenium / java framework for angular based web application. I have to run my tests across Chrome, Edge and Firefox. For Chrome & edge  there are no issues at all during test execution. But, the firefox browser runs very fast everytime.

**So, is there any specific idea on controlling the firefox execution speed? (OR) do we always need to develop a framework with browser specific code? Please share your ideas.**

**Selenium version: 3.141.59**

Comment: Thread.sleep(10*1000);

Comment: You can try to use system `sleep` to confirm whether it is the execution speed issue. If it is, then check "the explicit waiting" you are using. Maybe that WebElement you are waiting for appears before the whole page is loaded.

Comment: You want your automation to go as fast as possible each time so why is this a problem? If you are running into issues where you are trying to interact with the page before it's loaded then you need to add `WebDriverWait`s in those cases. Don't slow execution down, improve your tests/framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using protractor? - protractortest.org - protractor is designed for angular applications and includes an additional sync methods. It extends the webdriver framework so what you've done doesn't need to be restarted.

Taken from the site:

> Automatic Waiting
>
> You no longer need to add waits and sleeps to your
> test. Protractor can automatically execute the next step in your test
> the moment the webpage finishes pending tasks, so you don’t have to
> worry about waiting for your test and webpage to sync.

I've used it in c# with reasonably good success.

Comment: No, i'm not using protractor. Selenium is the requirement.

Comment: @Sangeetha Protractor extends selenium - you create/wrap your webdriver in an ngdriver object. The webdriver is still accessible from within it and you can still do everything selenium can do  but with added functionality to support angular